# Build(escape) a JavaScript regexp in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, mongodb

The scenario: Users type a keyword(e.g. `hello`) in my `asp.net` `mvc` application and then click `search`, in the `C#` code I build a `JavaScript` `RegExp` string(`/hello/i`), which will be passed into a query of `MongoDB`, the whole query looks like:

```
db.Posts.find( { "title" : /hello/i } )
```

to get all posts with `hello` in its title.

When the keyword contains special characters (like `\` or `(`), the `js regexp` is built incorrectly.

Is there any `C#` library to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Regex.Escape`.

Although Javascript and .Net use different regex engines, I believe that the .Net escaper is good enough for a JS regex.

Comment: Yes, the .NET flavor is effectively a superset of JavaScript's.  Any character that has special meaning in JS is also special in .NET, and will be correctly escaped.

Comment: @DannyChen: In simple cases, this will certainly work.  It's the corner cases that I'm not sure about.

Comment: For the character forward slash '/', it seems that it is recognized as normal character in C# but as reserved character in Javascript. Is it right?